# How to improve CPU utilization of a C++ Program

Tags: c++, performance, micro-optimization

This is a minimum debuggable version of the program. I am doing continuous vector allocation and sleeping for 20ms. The 20ms is just to mimick an external call which in real program will take ~200ms.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <chrono>
#include <vector>
void fun(){
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 500; i++){
        std::vector<unsigned char> vec;
        vec.resize(15000);
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(20));//mimicking a 20ms external call
    }
}
int main(){
    std::vector<std::thread> vecThread;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        vecThread.push_back(std::thread(fun));
    }

    for (std::thread& th : vecThread){
        if (th.joinable()){
            th.join();
        }
    }
}
```

I ran Intel VTune Profiler and found that the CPU utilization is poor.

How can I improve the CPU utilization of this code?

[image]

Comment: Perhaps instead of sleep you could do some actual work in the threads.

Comment: After you've awakend your threads and given them some actual work, also use std::thread::hardware_concurrency() instead of hard coded 6.

Comment: The pc is capable of running more than 6 threads. 6 is just a number I have chosen for the example. Also the sleep is just to mimick an external API call which takes roughly around 200ms in actual code.

Comment: I'm puzzled why you want the CPU utilization to be high. I'd guess the opposite would be more desirable.

Comment: @Jellyboy since I am spinning more threads, I want all the CPUs to be utilized. Can you please explain?

Comment: When you call sleep, you are giving up the thread to the kernel which will then schedule another process on that core. So it does not count towards your process.

Comment: Like I mentioned sleep is just an example, the result doesn't change even if I do something like iterating the elements in vector

Comment: @Jellyboy: If it takes a certain number of CPU-seconds to get some amount of work done, increasing utilization means getting that many CPU-seconds of work done in fewer seconds of wall-clock real time.  As is, the program spends a lot of its time waiting for some "external call" (whatever that is, whether I/O or something else we don't know), not overlapping work with it.  Obviously here, where it's just "sleep" and the later work doesn't depend on any result, you can just overlap all the sleeps with the `std::vector` resize / loop and be done much faster.

Comment: The hard part of parallelizing real programs is the serial dependencies between steps.  If there aren't any, you just overlap everything in as many threads as the machine has cores.  So with the details shown in this [mcve], there isn't a useful answer that's likely to still apply to your real program, unless you can run your "external call" in multiple threads at once.  Obviously `sleep` doesn't use CPU time, so it's going to profile as low utilization.  If the "external call" is I/O, that's true for it, too, so you might want more threads than cores depending on I/O parallelism.

Comment: @Jellyboy: I agree in this state the question doesn't appear useful / sensible.  Just use many more threads and loop fewer times inside each worker, so more sleeps are overlapping.  I think I can see what the original problem might have been, where that answer might or might not apply, hence my comments.

Comment: @PeterCordes quite frankly I have no idea what the goal here is. Whether you sleep or wait on a read() you will transition to the kernel and cpu utilization will be less than 100%. Unless you spin at 100% CPU (nonblock read) then MAYBE you will get close to 100%. As it is, the close to 0% utilization is exactly what's expected.

Comment: @PeterCordes i tried running more threads with lesser loops and still I am seeing the same under utilization of CPU

Comment: 20ms is a long time vs. the time to allocate and construct 15 kB of zeros.  That's probably a few microseconds, so you'll need many more threads, and even then at best you can get the program's total time down to just over 20ms, probably spending a decent amount of CPU time just on starting threads.

Comment: Just tried it myself on x86-64 Arch GNU/Linux, on i7-6700k Skylake, `clang++ -O2 -pthreads` with `6 * 500` threads each doing 1 iteration, and got it to run in 0.09 sec wall-clock, 0.0125 user-time, 0.167 system time. (`perf stat` says 150 ms task-clock, 1.68 CPUs utilized on average.)  The system clock speed was an average of 3.6GHz during this.  (With `/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/energy_performance_preference` set to `performance`, so it aggressively turbos to max.)  So anyway, most of the total CPU time was spend in the kernel, handling page faults from touching that new memory.

Comment: The new memory here refers to the vector resize of 15kB?

Comment: Not all allocators scale. In fact most do not scale perfectly. You can try to use jemalloc  (and/or tcmalloc) for example to check if the behaviour changes. Besides this, `resize` will write zeros into the memory and if the allocator is not good, this will cause some slow page-faults followed by writes in RAM (instead of the cache). Even worse: regarding the code of resize, it may cause memory reads on x86 processors. The RAM is a shared resource and thus do not scale with the number of cores. Sidenote: I find unexpected not to reserve `vecThread` to the 6 (moving threads is not great).